# Using Scrapy to Scrape Title and Duration Information on Youtube User Pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, scrapy

As the title suggests, I want to build an application that stores user video title information and duration and store it using Scrapy.

It's relatively easy to use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML source, but when dealing with Youtube user pages that have uploaded a significant number of videos, I don't think it's possible to use BeautifulSoup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @stovfl I've yet to start any coding. I don't have an understanding of how Youtube dynamically loads more videos on a user page after clicking the "Load more" button. Is there a particular way to load the entire HTML at once so that I can see the source of all the video objects?

Comment: Read this relevant SO QA to start: [youtube-get-url-video-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854168/python-youtube-get-url-video-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)

```
youtube-dl --get-title --get-duration (youtube link)
```